# Langrange Mean Value Theorem on tanx at x belongs to (0,π/2)

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity, mean-value-theorem

I know the basic requirements that say that function must be continuous in closed interval but if we consider (0,π/2) as [0,lim x-π/2 ] then can it be considered allright .tanx is continuous in this domain as well as differentiable everywhere except end points

Am I making a mistake Here

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am saying that tanx will be right side continuous at 90 degrees so can we consider Langrange's MVT for an open interval containing π/2